# Can someone explain this to me?

Tags: c++

Ok I'm sure this will get closed as its probably not a real question, but before that happens, I'm really curious on something: [Why is this program erroneously rejected by three C++ compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers)

I'm just now taking a data structures and algorithms course, so I'm not really skilled in C++ and have only dealt with basic stuff, so I have no idea what the above joke is all about. Its gotten so many votes and people said they couldnt stop laughing, but I dont get it at all. Can someone explain this?

Comment: He tried to compile the `.png`, not a textfile with that code.

Comment: Perhaps most of the comments are because an image file, or picture, is being fed to the compilers.  Compiler's don't like pictures, they prefer text in a file created by an editor or saved as text from a word processor.

Comment: It really wasn't all *that* funny.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of feeding the program to the compiler as text, he used a bitmap (PNG, if memory serves) file containing a picture of hand written code. Nothing more (or less) than that...

Comment: And really, not that funny.  I gave it 0.28 chuckles.

Comment: Now I noticed who posted it.  `chuckles += 1.0;`