# Subtraction problems in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So, in my JavaScript web app calculator, the addition works great. But, when I try to code the subtraction calculator, everything goes right, except for when I try the calculator out, the addition works fine, but when I try to subtract two numbers, it just says: NaN
Here's my calculator. The subtraction calculator begins at the paragraph that says "Subtraction Calculator!"

Here's  my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Addition Calculator!</p>
    <input id="n1" value=""/>
    <input id="n2" value=""/>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    <p id="answer"></p>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {

        var n1=document.getElementById("n1").value;

        var n2=document.getElementById("n2").value;
        answer = ( Number(n1) + Number(n2) );

        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=answer;
    }


    </script>
    <p>Subtraction Calculator!</p>
    <input id="sn1" value=""/>
    <input id="sn2" value=""/>
    <button type="button" onclick="subtract()">Submit</button>
    <p id="sanswer"></p>

    <script>
    function subtract() {
        var sn1=document.getElementById("sn1").value;
        var sn1=document.getElementById("sn2").value;
        stotal = ( Number(sn1) - Number(sn2) );
        document.getElementById("sanswer").innerHTML=stotal;
    }


    </script>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have to hate my post.. It's just a question...

Comment: You probably want to [make a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate this, instead of sharing code in Google Docs. That document may not be available for future visitors finding this question (you might delete it), whereas it will probably live a bit longer on JSFiddle.

Comment: Code in google docs - it's something I see for the first time

Comment: Downvotes don't mean that someone "hates" your question. It means "This question doesn't show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Don't take it personally. As for code formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code. There was also a yellow `?` button for the help and a box with tips on the right hand side when you were typing the question.

Comment: @zerkms I love writing programs in Microsoft Office PowerPoint. Sometimes, Word is better.

Comment: @Ian: initially read it as "MS Paint". PowerPoint isn't that extreme

Comment: @zerkms Well whatever! Maybe I use MacPaint!

Comment: Well, since only one person here kind of helped, guess I'll just go look somewhere else...

Comment: @zerkms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588649/how-did-this-person-code-hello-world-with-microsoft-paint

Comment: @user2506919: "guess I'll just go look somewhere else" - noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this line:

```
var sn1=document.getElementById("sn2").value;
```

You have a typo that you're creating a second `sn1` variable instead of `sn2`. Which means on this line:

```
stotal = ( Number(sn1) - Number(sn2) );
```

...you might expect a reference error when you use `sn2` but the browser is instead picking up the element with `id="sn2"` which gives `NaN` when run through the `Number()` function. And a subtraction involving `NaN` gives `Nan`.

So make it `sn2 = ...` and it'll be fine.

(Noting that as a general rule it is better not to use variable names that are the same as element ids, because then you don't accidentally get this sort of "weird" behaviour.)

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/ivobew/1/edit

Comment: ctrl+f, "typo"; mark as too localized.

Comment: Confirmed that it works after this is fixed http://jsbin.com/opuzoh/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Misnamed variable:

```
function subtract() {
        var sn1=document.getElementById("sn1").value;
        var sn1=document.getElementById("sn2").value;
        stotal = ( Number(sn1) - Number(sn2) );
        document.getElementById("sanswer").innerHTML=stotal;
    }
```

Second `sn1` should be `sn2`.