# can a image url contain a written virus

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i was trying to insert image urls into my database but I was wondering can image urls contain virus written in the url itself. I've looked around for the answer but can't find the answer.
like this. I've seen real huge urls about a page long. Like this url below could that be a virus.
http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/8/8b/AoU_Hulk_03.png/revision/latest?cb=20150310161344

data:image/jpeg;base64,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

Comment: That last part of your question is completely normal. Just the raw data for the image.

Comment: you mean an **image data uri** - because, an `image url` would be something like `http://example.com/path/to/image.png` - and that string of text is unlikely to contain a virus - the destination could, but the url itself could not cause any issues ... well, chrome had an issue once, but all you could do was crash chrome with a specifically crafted URL

Comment: An uploaded file to a server (by a hacker) disguising itself as an image can contain a virus and gets renamed and potentially cause havoc. So the short answer is "yes". I.e.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675941/how-can-a-virus-exist-in-an-image

Comment: Further reading http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55061/can-malware-be-attached-to-an-image

Comment: Question: Is this part of the URL? `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD.....` ??

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know they can't.

If a user is able submit urls to your database you have to be wary of SQL injection though.

Comment: Your first line *As far as I know they can't.*; untrue. The second however, you're right.

Comment: @Fred -ii-I think you misunderstood OP's question. OP was wondering if the image url could contain a virus not the image itself.

Comment: this following part of that URL `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD....` contains image data. If that data has been manipulated in any way, then it could pose a potential threat. I posted a comment under the question. Let's see if they can clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, in image can't be virus. It's interpreted by some image viewer, but in image isn't executable code and image viewer doesn't execute image code.

Comment: Truth: *"A JPEG is a file can get infected. However, in order to activate the virus, the file must be run. As the JPEG file is an image file, it will not be executed as long as the image is not processed by any other type of program. 
Hence, if the image is executed by a program like a library or a database, the system can get infected."* - Sources http://ccm.net/faq/384-myth-a-jpeg-file-can-contain-a-virus and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55061/can-malware-be-attached-to-an-image