# std::string in a .c file

Tags: c++, c, std

I've seen `std::string` used in a `.c` file. std is a c++ namespace and namespaces were introduced in c++. Why is that so? Shouldn't it throw an error?

Comment: File extensions don't matter, I can write code in a *.mp3 file, and my compiler will happily compile it as C++ if I ask it to.

Comment: @Praetorian:  [But maybe not a .png file.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, I think there's a video somewhere of someone imaging a BMP or something and changing the extension to a working C++ program.

Comment: @chris Watch the gif from the second answer in James' link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it will cause numerous compiler errors if it's compiled as C code.  If it's being compiled as C++ instead, then it will compile fine.  For example, GCC has the `-x` option to select the language to compile as, so you can compile a `.c` as C++ if you want with `-x c++`.  Likewise, the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler has the options `/Tc` and `/Tp` to select a source language of C and C++ respectively.

I suggest you fix your build system so that it doesn't pass the `-x c++` or `/Tp` flag to files not ending with typical C++ source file extensions (`.cc`, `.cpp`, `.cxx`, `c++`, and `.C`, though the last three are quite rare).

Answer (score 1):

The extension of a file is only there to help you as the reader. The compiler does not care as long as you use a c++ compiler.