# Unexpected result from math expression

Tags: ruby, irb

i am using ruby irb

```
   -1/4
=> -1
   0-1
=> -1
   0-1/4
=> 0
```

How come it'll be zero for 0-1/4 ?

My calculation is as shown in below pic[image]

Comment: As I noted in my solution, your calculation is wrong. Basic order of operations - division before subtraction.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers/5509621 for a similar question. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1/4` is zero - since both operands are integers, the result is floored to an integer as well. This is the same behavior you're observing earlier with `-1/4`.

If you want a non-integer result, one or both of the operands have to be floats. For example:

```
0 - 1 / 4.to_f
```

`to_f` makes the interpreter interpret the number as a float.

edit: Your calculation is wrong, by the way. `0 - 1/4` is NOT the same as `(0-1) / 4`. Always do your operations in the correct order!

Answer (score 1):

Because 1 / 4 is 0. And 0 - 0 is 0.

```
0 - (1 / 4)
```

You want this:

```
(0 - 1) / 4
```

This way you make sure that subtraction happens first. Read up on operator precedence.