# no operator '>>' matches these operands

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

my program wont compile because it did not found match for the operand.
It accesses the map in struct Student, I am not sure if this is the exact way to access map.

my program wont compile because it did not found match for the operand.
It accesses the map in struct Student, I am not sure if this is the exact way to access map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <list>


using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string id;
    map<string, int> scores;
};

istream& operator >>(istream &is, Sudent& g) {

    auto it = g.scores.begin();
    is >> g.id >> it->first >> it.second;
    return is;
}
```

On `>> it->first` I get this error:

```
Error: no operator ">>" matches these operands
    operand types are: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>> >> const std::string
```

Comment: Please post code as text and not an image.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: how is that any where even remotely close to being a duplicate?

Comment: Check the definition of istream, the operator is not ok with it.

Answer (score 6):

You may use temporary variables

```
std::string tempStr;
int tempInt;
is >> g.id >> tempStr >> tempInt;
scores.insert( std::pair<std::string,int>(tempStr , tempInt));
```

Comment: Right solution, but needs an explanation of why what the OP did was wrong. Solution without explanation leads to cargo cult behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

The error is due to the fact that `it->first` is of type `const string`, not `string`.

Apart from this, you need to find a way to read that map by reading an (unknown) number of string(s) and the corresponding int.  How to do that depends on how they are stored in the file.

Comment: Why would `it->first` be `const`, though? `g` is not `const`, and `g.scores` is not `const`, so why is the `const` version of `g.scores.begin()` being called? Is it a side effect of using `auto` to accept a return value from an overloaded method? Changing `auto` to `map<string,int>::iterator` should fix the error.

Comment: it->first is const because in a map the key is immutable. Allow to change it->first would mean change the position/order of the object inside the container. That's equivalent to an deletion/insertion