# Compiling a CPP program with a .c extension

Tags: c++, g++

Today I accidentally added the extension '.c' on a CPP program (with namespaces, classes and whatnot inside) and passed it to g++. It compiled it without an issue, but shouldn't it have treated it as a C Program and throw an error or a warning? On other threads I read that the extension for g++ doesn't matter (some suggest using any arbitrary extension that's not taken, however I tried other extension asides from the standard .c,.C,.cpp etc) and they are not recognised.

So, what exactly happens here with the extensions? Was my cpp program compiled as a cpp program or as a c one?

Comment: how did you invoke the compiler? What exactly did you type on your command line?

Comment: What happens if you use the `gcc` toolchain driver instead of the `g++` toolchain driver?

Comment: Does this anwer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc

Comment: I just compiled it using g++ like so, g++ -o pr.o pr.c and it compiled fine.  Also, using GCC won't work at all (meaning it won't compile). Worth noting I compiled it on WSL, not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: The answer on the proposed dupe explains what flags on gcc are more or less equivalent to calling just g++

Comment: So, from what I can understand after all it will compile any compatible file as a .cpp program. This thread however says that g++ would accept any file extension not already 'taken: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369583/does-it-matter-which-file-extension-i-use-for-my-c-programs . So I even tried something like '.frog' as an extension, which g++ doesn't recognise. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

> It compiled it without an issue, but shouldn't it have treated it as a C Program

No, it should't've. g++ treats files with .c suffix as C++ sources by default.

> Was my cpp program compiled as a cpp program?

Yes.

> On other threads I read that the extension for g++ doesn't matter

This is not exactly correct. g++ does detect language based on the file suffix, but if C is detected, then C++ is used to compile the file instead by default. The default can be overridden by specifying the `-x LANG` option. `g++ -x none` will detect language in same way as gcc would.

Comment: So, regardless g++ will compile any compatible source file as a c++ program. However, it won't compile if suffix is something like .py for instance, so where does the idea that it doesn't care about suffixes come from?  Referring to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369583/does-it-matter-which-file-extension-i-use-for-my-c-programs

Comment: @pol Probably from the fact that .c is compiled as C++. If you only ever test .c and .cpp suffixes, then you might make the misleading conclusion that the suffix doesn't matter. Or, the answer may have been written from perspective that **if** you specify the language to the compiler **then** the suffix doesn't matter. Indeed, the suffix only matters in case the language is deduced.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted your code here, I am assuming it doesn't have any special libraries included in it that are privileged only to g++ compiler.
As per your query, the c++ code can be compiled by gcc just fine as it chooses the best compiler based on the file extension and the same thing can be said about g++ compiler compiling the C though it compiles both .c and .cpp codes just as c++.

Lastly, I will say that it's not good practice and can cause linker problems ( Some functions or libraries are missing errors ).
Even though if you want so bad, it could work if you change the compilation line to this

```
gcc <file_name>.c -lstdc++
```

Comment: Actually, my current code does have iostream and namespaces inside, so it can't be compiled by gcc at all.