# What is NoMethodError in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not a newbie in rails so this is embarassing but I keep getting a nomethoderror I don't know what s happening.

this is the error

[image]

and this is my controller

[image]

Comment: Please read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) document and put source code in plain text instead of images.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]", then remove the images and copy/paste the text of the message into the question, along with the _absolute minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem. [We can't reuse an image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/128421), nor can the search engines index them, which helps others find your question and solve their coding problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `find_item` you are setting `@post`, not `@item`, which makes it nil on the view.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there's no matching method in the instance that you're accesing in this case, in this case if you look at the `show` action it only does the `find_item` and the `find_item` only returns a `@post` instance not an `@item` instance.

Just change `@post` to `@item` in the controller

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord automatically gives you getter and setter methods for the instance attributes. `@item.title` calls `title` method on the `@item` object. If the method is not defined on the object on which it is being called then `NoMethodError` exception is raised.

The error that you see when you access show is because @item instance variable is not initialized in the controller and thus not available in the view file `show.html.erb`, i.e. it is nil by default and Rails is complaining that there is no method title on the `nil` object(as nil object doesnt have that method, `@item` or `@post` might have it depending on whether the respective table has that column)