# Incomplete type is not allowed (c++ VSCODE)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code

I have simply created an Array `a` using container class. However, VScode's IntelliSense is showing an error. Here's an implementation of selection sort.

[image: ![IntelliSense Error]

the contents of the `c_cpp_properties.json` file are as follows

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.16299.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.13.26128/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

the code compiles and runs successfully. How do I fix the incorrect IntelliSense error?

Comment: Please include a [MCVE] as *text* in the body of the question. Images of tiny snippets leave out critical context and prevent us from reproducing your error. In this case, knowing whether you actually did `#include <array>` and have a using statement to avoid the need to `std::` qualify `array` are kind of important.

Comment: You probably need `#include <array>` remember that intellisense is a different compiler than the one the actually compiles your code.

Comment: I have included `bits/stdc++.h` header. let me edit the question.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: I understand the consequences of including `bits/stdc++.h`. However, I am getting the same error for the `print` macro I defined. why is that?

Comment: "I understand the consequences" \*asks about the consequences\*

Comment: I tried to paste your screen snapshot into my IDE, but my IDE could not compile the image.  Please edit your post with the text from the IDE (hint: highlight with mouse, copy to clipboard, then paste into your question).

Comment: The compiler that is used for intellisense may not have that header.

Comment: read: almost certainly does not have that header

Comment: @ThomasMatthews [thief](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/560648) :P

Comment: also [stop `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: Yes, I know that too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Stop including `bits/stdc++.h`.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

That's an implementation header for some toolchains. It's not for you.

Include the proper header instead:

```
#include <array>
```

*(It's likely that your Intellisense engine does not have access to this internal header from Linuxy platforms.)*

By the way, [you're not allowed to choose names that begin with two underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/560648). So stop that too.

Comment: Yes. The compiler intellisense uses does not have `bits/stdc++.h` and including `array` fixed it. However removing __ from the macro didn't fix the error

Comment: I didn't say removing `__` would fix the error, I said you're not allowed to use it. It could break in the future. Honestly this should have been covered by your book :/

Comment: ***However removing __ from the macro didn't fix the error*** That can cause other problems.

Comment: @drescherjm yes. It did. Thank you. I will fix it.