# why does argv remove some of my characters?

Tags: c++, cmd, escaping

[image: cmd input and output]

I'm new to c++ and I just started using *argc* and *argv* for my project. However, when I try to print out *argv* like in the picture, it keeps removing the character *^* or asks me for more. I'm using visual studio and I just updated it to the latest version.

Comment: please include code and output as text in the question. Not everybody can follow links and not everybody can view images, and nobody can copy-paste the image to compile it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers))

Comment: `^` means something in the command window. Type echo `^^` to see this in cmd.exe

Comment: there is nothing much with the code really. I just enter the input via cmd and print out argv[1] using cout << argv[1] <<endl

Comment: `^` is cmd's escape character. See [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html), for instance.

Comment: The code is not the problem. The problem is an understanding of `cmd.exe` behavior. To avoid this behavior make sure the user uses double quotes around the argument and remove the outer quotes in your c++ code. For example look at  `echo "^^"` versus `echo ^^` in cmd.exe

Comment: See the section _Parsing C++ command-Line arguments_ at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=vs-2019

Comment: This is important from the previous comment / link ***The caret character (^) is not recognized as an escape character or delimiter. The character is handled completely by the command-line parser in the operating system before being passed to the argv array in the program.***

Answer (score 2):

That's because in `cmd`, `^^` is an escape sequence for `^`. So if you enter `^^` it will only send one `^` to your program, as explained [here](https://riptutorial.com/batch-file/example/32077/escape-using-caret---).

You can see this if you put `echo ^^` into the command line, which will print `^`.

The reason why it asks for more sometimes is because you inputted an odd amount of `^`, so the escape sequence isn't complete any you have to enter more characters to fix that.