# Can we have a structure as data type of a variable in another structure? in c++

Tags: c++

I am supposed to Implement a structure-based Library Information System. I have to create many structures including the following two structures(SBook and ABookList) with the different variables in both the structures. I want to ask that can we have a structure(SBook) as the data type of a variable or array(books) in another structure(ABookList)? see the code below. I have implemented and its almost working in my case but I did it by experiment, I want to know the concept behind it. Thanks.

[***Code:***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpoaU.png)

Comment: You can have any type as a structure member, except itself. The concept behind it is that user-defined types are treated the same as built-in types. This was a novel idea in the late 1950s – early 1960s, but is generally taken for granted these days.

Comment: Please post code as text into the question. Don't link to external resources. I recommend [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: your code already does what you are asking for. Why do you have doubts whether this can be done?

Comment: also your `sbook` does contains `string`s and `std::string` is no different from a type you define yourself

Comment: there are several reasons why code should not be posted as images. For  one see [Why is this program erroneously rejected by three C++ compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers), more seriously, not everybody can view images

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need a struct that contains only an array of another struct (it seems an overkill), you can do something simpler like so:

```
struct book
{
   int id;
   string bookName;
}
```

and when you need an array of book instanciate an array like so:

```
book arrayOfBooks[10];
```