# Rotate Array -> Given an integer array nums, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative

Tags: c++, arrays

Today I came across this problem on leetcode

[image]

My Approach --

[image]

So here I am trying to create a new modified array which has one more index than my orginal array and copy the original indexes values to new array by shifiting one indexes
Let's say my original array is `{1,2,3,4}` of size 4 so I created the modified array of size 5 and put the original array as `{garbage value,1,2,3,4}` then my idea is to swap the last index of the modified array to its first index which will make array as `{4,1,2,3,garbage value}` then transfer this modified array again to my original array so on transferring my orginal array will become as `{4,1,2,3}`.
Then repeat this process K times as asked in the question. Yeah I know my approach is complex and lengthy but please tell me where did I did the mistake in coding because I think my logic should be correct.

II Approach - 2nd approach will be save the last element in temp variable and shift the array from `i->i+1` index then add the temp on first index.

Comment: use [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: *Then repeat this process K times as asked in the question* -- This is a prime example of being fooled by Leetcode in providing naive, easy to code solutions.  Those solutions will not work for larger values, all due to "time limit exceeded" errors.  There is no need to actually write a loop to rotate the items.  What if `K` were a million?

Comment: we cannot help you with your code because we cannot  compile an image. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers. Code should be included as text in the question

Comment: how would you do it with pen and paper? You wouldnt write down the same array 20 times shifted by 1 in each step to shift it by 20 but rather you would pass the input once and for each element place it at the new shifted position.

Comment: You're probably doing things the wrong way around, you should first learn C++ before you start doing competitive coding.

Comment: Start learning C++ from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (make sure it is up-to-date and not teaching you "C"), A good online site is [learncpp.com](https://learncpp.com/) and use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to explore what C++ has to offer (containers/algorithms). 
Cpprefence usually also has good examples on how to use the standard library. And lastly refer to the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) on how to really use C++ as it is intended to be used.

Comment: `int modified[m]` -- This is not valid C++.  Your example already uses `std::vector`, so why didn't you use it here?  --> `std::vector<int> modified(m);`

Comment: To add to my first comment, take your input and rotate it 98 times (a multple of 7).  You end up with the same unchanged array, so there was no need to rotate anything.  That is a hint to use modulus in some way.

Comment: This obviously a homework, short answer would be the 1st comment. But since this is an exercise, you need provide your own implementation after reading the reference text and class notes. Then guys may give you advice on bugs and pitfalls.

Comment: In the first iteration of the outer loop `i` is `0` and you call `swap(modified[i], modified[m-1])`. But `modified[i]` doesn't have a value yet .. Because you start filling your `modified` array at index `1`

Answer (score 0):

this is my approach for the question just i have use minimization on k value

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;     
#define ll  long long




int main()
 {
    ll n;
    cin>>n;
    ll k;
    cin>>k;
    ll a[n];
    for(ll i=0;i<n;i++) cin>>a[i];

    k=k%n;// after n roation array will become same so optimise number of operation
    int ans[n];
    int left_pointer=0;int right_pointer=n-1;
    for(ll i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(k>=0&&right_pointer-k+1<n)
        {
            ans[i]=a[right_pointer-k+1];
           k--;

        }
        else{
            ans[i]=a[left_pointer];
            left_pointer++;
        }
    } 
    for(ll i=0;i<n;i++) cout<<ans[i]<<" ";

    
    return 0;
}
```