# confuse on building and using dll with c++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll

### Background

I'm a rookie and I'm learning how to build and use dll in c++ through microsoft official guidance.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170

I found that it use a header file with checking whether there exist certain macro(MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS) to obtain two edition of MATHLIBRARY_API macro definition. Then use this header file either in DLL building project and client project.

I don't know where the macro(MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS) definition is and I want to try building a DLL just use "__declspec(dllexport)", so I create two project to in visual studio to test.

### Question

In the dll-building project, I only use "dllexport" before function declaration in header file and build a dll successfully. What confuse me is it can works while I include this header in client project and give me a correct result(print "hello world" in console).
Is this normal? Why I don't need declare the function as "dllimport" and it can works?[header file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vHKM.png)[client project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNIJQ.png)[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHxHP.png)

Comment: It should be defined in the c/c++ preprocessor symbols project setting of your DLL provided you used the DLL template to create your dll project. In either case it needs to be enabled for the dll project otherwise the export macro will not work. This is something we had to manually add long ago.

Comment: Any attempt of reading the picked tag descriptions? [tag:C]: *C is distinct from C++ and it should not be combined with the C++ tag.* [Why is this program erroneously rejected by three C++ compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers)

Comment: This setting is at: `Project Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc:  [Import into an application using __declspec(dllimport)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-into-an-application-using-declspec-dllimport?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019)

Using __declspec(dllimport) is optional on function declarations, but the compiler produces more efficient code if you use this keyword. However, you must use __declspec(dllimport) for the importing executable to access the DLL's public data symbols and objects. Note that the users of your DLL still need to link with an import library.